# Javascript - I can't find my mistake.(radio buttons)

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I want to create an online test,but there is something wrong with my first question.The code below doesn't work and returns "your score is 0" even when the right answer is checked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>sssdsdsdsd

<head>Mypage.com
<title> myPage</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<script>
var total=0;
var yourmark="your score is  ";

if(document.getElementById('q12').checked) {
  total=total+1;
}else {
 total=total;
}

</script>

<script>
function showScore() {
    alert(yourmark + total  );
}
</script>
</br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" id="q11" value="false">Question 1-first option <br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" id="q12"  value="true" > Question 1- second option<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="false">Question 1- third option<br>



<button onclick="showScore()">Show my score</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You added script that is executing before the document has been fully loaded, meaning your check of the radio buttons is doing nothing

Comment: **Move** your score calculation **inside** your `showScore()` function. You're *almost* there.

Comment: Change the Java tag to JavaScript

Comment: @Barranka: [codereview.se] takes working code and reviews it to make it better, it's not designed to fix broken/not-currently-working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgJuA

So, leave var total = 0 as global variable outside the functions and create a function `checkAnswer()` .
Your javascript part now will be:

```
var total = 0;    
function checkAnswer() {
    //total is the global Variable for the score
    if (document.getElementById('q12').checked) {
        total = total + 1;
    } else {
        total = total;
    }
    return total;    
}

function showScore() {
    var yourmark = "your score is  ";
    alert(yourmark + checkAnswer());
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

The *immediate* reasons why things are not working as you want are listed.

1. You set the value of the total before the elements are parsed and rendered.  HTML will parse from top to bottom.  Therefore you want to move your script to the bottom.
2. If you need to set the value of the option box in the markup, use checked instead of value attribute.

You should have something like the snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>sssdsdsdsd

<head>Mypage.com
<title> myPage</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<script>
function showScore() {
    alert(yourmark + total  );
}
</script>
</br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" id="q11">Question 1-first option <br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" id="q12"  checked="true" > Question 1- second option<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1">Question 1- third option<br>



<button onclick="showScore()">Show my score</button>


<script>
var total=0;
var yourmark="your score is  ";

if(document.getElementById('q12').checked) {
  total=total+1;
}else {
 total=total;
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This block:

```
var total=0;
var yourmark="your score is  ";

if(document.getElementById('q12').checked) {
  total=total+1;
}else {
 total=total;
}
```

runs at the beginning of of the page, as it is loading. At this point `total` is, in fact `0`. When you click the button, all you're asking for is the value of 'total`. At no point are you updating the value of`total` after you change the options.

The simplest solution, as *PM 77-1* suggested, is to move the calculation inside the function, so that `total` is calculated every time you need an updated answer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>sssdsdsdsd

<head>Mypage.com
<title> myPage</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<script>
function showScore() {
  var total=0;
  var yourmark="your score is  ";

  if(document.getElementById('q12').checked) {
    total=total+1;
  }else {
   total=total;
  }
  
  alert(yourmark + total  );
}
</script>
</br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" id="q11" value="false">Question 1-first option <br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" id="q12"  value="true" > Question 1- second option<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="false">Question 1- third option<br>



<button onclick="showScore()">Show my score</button>



</body>
</html>
```