# javascript conditional statement for a group of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, button, radio-button, statements

I want to make an online test, but i have some problems with the code below.

I want it to mark the correct and wrong answers, and show the score, when the button is pressed.

Now I have the following problem: I want the first switch statement to be only for the first group of radio buttons, the second switch statement for the second group of buttons, and so on.

How could I do that? When I run the code now, the colors change even though none of the radio buttons is checked, or when a button in only one of the groups is checked.

```js
function showScore() {
  var check;
  var total = 0;
  var yourmark = "your score is  ";

  switch (document.getElementById('q12').checked) {
    case true:
      total = total + 1;
      document.getElementById('text1').style.color = "green";
      break;
    case false:
      document.getElementById('text0').style.color = "red";
      document.getElementById('text2').style.color = "red";
      document.getElementById('text1').style.color = "green";
      break;
  }
  switch (document.getElementById('q13').checked) {
    case true:
      document.getElementById('text0.1').style.color = "green";
      total = total + 1;
      break;
    case false:
      document.getElementById('text1.1').style.color = "red";
      document.getElementById('text1.2').style.color = "red";
      break;
  }

  alert(yourmark + total);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="question1" id="q11" value="false">
<text id="text0">Question 1-first option</text>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" id="q12" value="true">
<text id="text1">Question 1- second option</text>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="false">
<text id="text2">Question 1- third option</text>

<br>
<br>

<input type="radio" name="question2" id="q13" value="false">
<text id="text0.1">Question 1-first option</text>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" id="q12" value="true">
<text id="text1.1">Question 1- second option</text>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="false">
<text id="text1.2">Question 1- third option</text>
<br>

<button onclick="showScore();">Show my score</button>
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use jQuery?

Comment: I see you are [moving ahead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109988/javascript-i-cant-find-my-mistake-radio-buttons). Have you tried to debug your code via browser tools?

Comment: You have **2** radio button elements with `q12` ID. Is it intentional?

Comment: no ID `text1.1`, use `text1_1`

Comment: What is `<text>`? You should use `<label>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var questions = document.forms.myForm.getElementsByClassName('question');
document.getElementById('showScore').onclick = function showScore() {
  var total = 0,
      correct = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<questions.length; ++i) {
    var chosen = questions[i].querySelector(':checked');
    if(chosen) {
      questions[i].classList.add('show-score');
      correct += chosen.value == 'true';
      ++total;
    }
  }
  alert("Your score is " + correct + " out of " + total);
};
```

```css
.question {
  margin: 1em 0; /* Separation between questions */
}
.question > label:after { /* Line-break after each answer */
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
.question.show-score > input[value=true]+label {
  color: green;
}
.question.show-score > input[value=false]+label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <div class="question">
    <input type="radio" name="question1" id="q-1-1" value="false">
    <label for="q-1-1">Question 1 - first option</label>
    
    <input type="radio" name="question1" id="q-1-2" value="true">
    <label for="q-1-2">Question 1 - second option</label>

    <input type="radio" name="question1" id="q-1-3" value="false">
    <label for="q-1-3">Question 1 - third option</label>
  </div>
  <div class="question">
    <input type="radio" name="question2" id="q-2-1" value="false">
    <label for="q-2-1">Question 2 - first option</label>
    
    <input type="radio" name="question2" id="q-2-2" value="true">
    <label for="q-2-2">Question 2 - second option</label>

    <input type="radio" name="question2" id="q-2-3" value="false">
    <label for="q-2-3">Question 2 - third option</label>
  </div>
  <button id="showScore">Show my score</button>
</form>
```

Note those changes:

- I have removed inline event listener from HTML, and added it using JS
- I removed those ugly `<br>` and used CSS instead
- I used `<label>` instead of invalid `<text>`. With `<label>`, you can also check a radio by clicking the text.
- Instead of setting the color of correct/wrong answers with JS, I used CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ehr: group them. There's a lot wrong with your code and html. Id's are inconsistent, you are using inline event handlers, the code itself is bulky etc.

If you group the radiobuttons with a surrounding div, use consistent id's, `labels` instead of the `<text>` tag, leave the label-formatting to css and use `querySelector[All]`, the code can be much shorter, really. Something like:

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', showScore);

function showScore(e) {
    var from = e.target || e.srcElement, fromtype = from.type;
    if ( !(fromtype && /radio/i.test(fromtype)) ) { return true; }
    var score = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked[value=true]').length;
    // .. do stuff with [score]
}
```

It's demonstrated in this j[**sFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/eeuo43hu/)